# How to check what link is clicked inside a div with only Class Name

Tags: javascript

I have this code. How can I capture the click event inside this div "dt-buttons" and check what specific link was clicked? I don't have access to change this code, so I want to capture the click event of these two a `href` to execute code.

```
<div id="table_1_wrapper" class="wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper">
    <div class="dt-buttons">
        <a class="dt-button new_table_entry DTTT_button DTTT_button_new" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" href="#"><span>New entry</span></a>
        <a class="dt-button edit_table DTTT_button DTTT_button_edit" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" href="#"><span>Edit</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to run some javascript code when this link is clicked. Hope some
one can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Select `#table_1_wrapper .DTTT_button`?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it. It calls a function when the link is clicked via onclick

```js
function a()
{console.log("link clicked")}
```

```html
<div id="table_1_wrapper" class="wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper">
    <div class="dt-buttons">
    <a class="dt-button new_table_entry DTTT_button DTTT_button_new" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" href="#" onclick="a()"><span>New entry</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using `addeventlistener`

```js
document.querySelector('.DTTT_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("Link Clicked")
})
```

```html
<div id="table_1_wrapper" class="wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper">
  <div class="dt-buttons">
    <a class="dt-button new_table_entry DTTT_button DTTT_button_new" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" href="#"><span>New entry</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not working on me, by the way, when New entry is click a pop up modal form will appear.

Comment: There might be some error in your code which is related to modal , because as you can see click capturing is done easily

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at (index):1290

Comment: You are referencing the element in a wrong way, such that js is not able to find that element

Answer (score 2):

You can use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to target the element using information from the parent and some of the classes of the `<a>` tag, like this:

```js
let myEle = document.querySelector("#table_1_wrapper a.dt-button");
myEle.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("clicked!"));
```

```html
<div id="table_1_wrapper" class="wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper">
    <div class="dt-buttons">
    <a class="dt-button new_table_entry DTTT_button DTTT_button_new" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" href="#"><span>New entry</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not working on me, by the way, when New entry is click a pop up form will appear.

Comment: Put `console.log(myEle)` just after `querySelector()` method to check if you get anything, if not you will have to use inspector tool to check the properties of the element an make an appropiate selector for it.

Comment: Nothing happens :(

Comment: Yes i am, there's an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at (index):1291

Comment: Is there a way that i can add "Onclick" attribute on that a href? This is wordpress based is there a code that can apply to functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) by passing all the element's classes without any spaces in between them:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var el = document.querySelector('.dt-button.new_table_entry.DTTT_button.DTTT_button_new');
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('element clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="table_1_wrapper" class="wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper">
    <div class="dt-buttons">
    <a class="dt-button new_table_entry DTTT_button DTTT_button_new" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" href="#"><span>New entry</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not working on me, by the way, when New entry is click a pop up modal form will appear.  Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at (index):1290

Comment: It worked now. Thanks! Now how can i use this to call function inside my functions.php on wordpress to get a variable value?

Comment: hi! Changed my question. I hope you can answer it too. Thanks!